# Как подключить телефон к компьютеру, чтобы его видел Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

У меня Windows XP 32 бит. Я нашла версию Android Studio, которая открылась и вроде бы работает. Но эмулятор не работает, т.к. оперативной памяти мало. Поэтому я решила подключить телефон к компьютеру. Но два телефона Самсунг и Xiaomi и планшет Леново компьютер прекрасно видит, а Android Studio не видит.
Во всех устройствах я включила "Отладка USB" и "передача файлов". Загрузила соответствующие драйверы (перепробовала кучу вариантов). В диспетчере устройств мои устройства есть и даже без жёлтых вопросительных знаков, но заменить виндовские драйверы на скачанные мной я не могу.
Нажимаю "Обновить драйвер", выбираю в папке нужный мне драйвер, нажимаю файл android_winusb.inf, нажимаю Открыть и он пишет:"В указанном месте отсутствуют сведения об оборудовании".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?